# How to scroll a ScrollPane in code?

Tags: java, libgdx

I’m trying to make a scrollwheel component like this in LibGDX:
[image]

I’m using ScrollPane since it has input and fling handling built in. I have an image for the scrollwheel that is divided into 14 sections, the scrollpane itself is two sections shorter so that there will be one section on the right and left sides that it can scroll to in either direction. Once the scroll position reaches the end in either direction I want to reset the scroll position back to the center. Doing this over and over again should create the illusion of an infinite scrolling wheel (hopefully).

The problem I’m having is how to position the ScrollPane in code to reset the image once it reaches either end. So far nothing I have tried to set the scroll position has worked. I’ve tried setScrollX() and scrollTo() methods. I’ve also tried setting the size of the scrollpane to be various sizes (same size as image and two sections smaller than the image). I’ve tried calling layout, invalidate, and pack on the scrollpane to make sure it is laid out correctly before I set the scroll value. I thought that updateVisualScroll() might force it to update the scroll position, but this also has no effect.

No matter what I do it simply ignores all of my calls to change the scroll position so I’m clearly missing something. In my code below I'm trying to get the scrollwheel to start in the center of the image and instead it's starting position is all the way at the left.

I also need to be able to get the current scroll position to detect when it has reached either end. I tried overriding the act() method and printing out scrollPane.getX(), but this value was always “0” even when I manually clicked and dragged it to scroll the ScrollPane.

The scrolling does work when manually clicking and dragging, so I believe the ScrollPane is set up correctly, I just can’t get it to scroll within the code.

Here is my code, and for simplicity I took all of my experimentation code out because none of my experimenting worked.

```
public class MyScrollWheel extends Container<ScrollPane> {
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;
    private Image image;
    private int scrollOffset;

    public MyScrollWheel(){
        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("internal/scrollwheel.png"));
        image = new Image(texture);

        scrollOffset = (int)(image.getWidth()/14);

        scrollPane = new ScrollPane(image);
        scrollPane.setOverscroll(false, false);

        setActor(scrollPane);
        size(image.getWidth()-(scrollOffset*2), image.getHeight());

        scrollPane.setScrollX(scrollOffset); // << this doesn't scroll
        scrollPane.updateVisualScroll();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using the `Slider` for this? You can get the amount inside the listener and can easily set it's position either inside or outside the listener.

Comment: Great idea, I'll give it a go and report back. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm running into a lot of problems with Slider also. In a Slider the knob is the part that moves so for my scrollwheel the knob has to be larger than the slider component itself, when this happens the knob won't move at all since there is no room for the knob to move. Also the entire knob drawable shows instead of being cropped off (like it does with a ScrollPane). If I make the knob smaller than the slider it will move (although click+drag doesn't seem to work as it just positions the slider all the way back to the left, which is odd). I'm not sure if Slider will work for this.

Comment: How about getting rid of the actor and make the background wrap horizontally and you edit the source x. Just with sprite batch I'm talking about. Check out Texture.wrap and perhaps make a class extending an actor when you get the hang of it.

Comment: I try to cook something up tomorrow if you don't have success

Comment: My app is entirely UI based and relies exclusively on Stage and a variety of different types of Actors. This scrollwheel is going to be added in along side other actors inside of a Table, so it does need to be an Actor. ScrollPane seems to do everything I need (crops the swcrollwheel image, click+drag scroll, fling, etc) except I can't figure out how to set the scroll position directly within the code...it seems like this would be possible to do. Any ideas how to make that work or would I need to modify the ScrollPane source code? And thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: No need to alter the source code since you can most probably extend `Scrollpane` ;)

Comment: I did try extending ScrollPane, but still couldn't get setScrollX() to do anything. Which is why I was wondering if I'd have to modify the code directly instead of trying to access it from the outside. But I like your scrollwheel better, so I'll go with that instead. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I hopefully managed to get something you can build upon. What I simply did was extending actor and have it accept a Texture so I could use Texture.wrap and have it draw with `SpriteBatch.draw()`. I am able to keep scrolling it now and based on the scroll delta you can figure out how far it has been scrolled. I don't see any need to reset the wheel but if you really want to you can just do `wheel.setScroll(0);`.

One limitation is that it is not a `Drawable` so it cannot be scaled like a `NinePatch`. You have to give it a plain wheel texture draw it the size you want it to spear, you can add normal scaling however and keep aspect ratio manually. Then add the sides to it and perhaps overlay a gradient on those to create depth.

*ScrollWheel:*

```
public class ScrollWheel extends Actor {
    Texture wheelTexture;
    private int scroll = 0;

    public int getScroll() {
        return scroll;
    }
    public void setScroll(int scroll) {
        this.scroll = scroll;
    }

    public ScrollWheel(Texture texture)
    {
        wheelTexture = texture;
        wheelTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);

        setWidth(texture.getWidth());
        setHeight(texture.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);

        batch.draw(wheelTexture, getX(), getY(), scroll, 0,
                wheelTexture.getWidth(), wheelTexture.getHeight());
    }
}
```

*usage in a Screen:*

```
public class TestScreen implements Screen {
    Stage stage;
    ScrollWheel wheel;

    public TestScreen() {
        stage = new Stage();
        Table t = new Table();
        t.setFillParent(true);
        stage.addActor(t);

        wheel = new ScrollWheel(new Texture("hud/wheel_part.png"));
        wheel.addListener(new DragListener() {
            @Override
            public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                super.drag(event, x, y, pointer);
                wheel.setScroll(wheel.getScroll() + (int)getDeltaX());
            }
        });

        t.add(wheel);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.3f, .36f, .42f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
    //...Other mandatory screen methods...
}
```

So just create a wheel texture that is tillable and include that with the ScrollWheel constructor. It will draw the wheel in the center of the screen if you use this exact code.

The `scroll` variable essentially holds the amount of scroll so if you you want limit this between 0 and 100 you would just add this functionality in `setScroll()`.

```
if (scroll > 100) scroll = 100; 
else if (scroll < 0) scroll = 0;
```

You could then add a step to it. So if you want to rotate a image with the slider you could set the rotation by `scroll * 3,6f` or `scroll * (maxScroll / maxStep)`

I really liked the way this turned out, I will be using this for my slider in the future :D. I have extended and altered it a bit already and you can see my implementation here: https://youtu.be/RNLk5B-VfYg

Comment: Wow, thanks! That is brilliant! :) I am having a problem because my main window is implemented in a scrollpane and the scrollwheel seems to fight with the scrollpane so the scrollwheel just barely moves a few pixels before it locks up and stops moving. If I remove the scrollpane it works perfectly so the problem is definitely the interaction between the scrollpane and scrollwheel. I believe it might be a focus problem, so I tried adding getStage().setScrollFocus(wheel); inside of the draglistener but that didn't fix it. Do you have any ideas? I can post sample code if needed.

Comment: In my previous game for a game jam I wanted to have dragable actors inside a scrollpane. But the scrollpane turned out to be a scrollpain in the ass since it overrides these kind of actions. I have no idea how to have it only function when dragging outside of a touchable actor.  There does not seem to be any straightforward implementation for this. The only thing I can think off is removing the listener when a touch is triggered on the wheel. Another workaround is to implement multiple "pages" instead of scrolling. You could still have the user fling the screen to go a full page up or down.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. A paged system won't work in my app because it's a scrolling UI with buttons, text fields, etc. and it can change its size based on user-defined settings. So figuring out a way to have ScrollPane let go of the input is my best option. My previous method of using a ScrollPane as the ScrollWheel did work as far as catching the input. The outer window would not scroll as long as I was scrolling on the ScrollWheel. The ScrollPane source code is where I got the idea to try the setScrollFocus method but that didn't work with your ScrollWheel.

Comment: Woot! I found out how to stop ScrollPane from from being a "ScrollPain". ;) See the very last post on this thread. I added this new listener to your ScrollWheel and it works perfectly now even inside of a ScrollPane. http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12612

Comment: And thanks again for all of your help. I really love this! I would also like to tweak it sometime in the future to include things like fling support and have it work with drawables. If I get these things working, I'll post an update when I finish it. :)

Comment: Menno Gouw, I just added my updates to your scroll wheel and I'd love to hear your thoughts/opinions on it or any further tweaks you have. Thanks again for all your help! I don't know that I would have considered designing one completely from scratch and probably would have just kept tinkering with the provided LibGDX components, but this was definitely the best way to go. It works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Menno Gouw's scroll wheel, I've added some more features:

- Fling support with setting for fling time
- Precision setting to adjust sensitivity of the wheel
- Takes a Drawable
- Compatible for use inside of a ScrollPane

***NOTE:*** For my purposes I have it take in a Label in the constructor, but this can easily be changed if you don't want it tied to a Label.

Here is a video I recorded on phone demoing the scroll wheel.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwVrez4BZsY&feature=youtu.be

**- EDIT 1:** Layout bugs have now been fixed (hopefully). It now updates its position when moved in a ScrollPane and the Drawables are clipped to the border of the Actor.

**- EDIT 2:** Added support for a stationary drawable for shading and a method to change the wheel's direction (setRightPositiveDirection()).

```
public class ScrollWheel extends Actor {
    private Drawable wheelDrawable, wheelShading;
    private Label label;

    private int unscaledScrollValueX=0, scrollValueX=0;
    private boolean isNotEdge;
    private int precision=40;
    private int direction=1;
    private int minValue=Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxValue=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    // MANUAL SCROLL
    private int separator;
    private int wheelWidth;
    // FLING
    private float flingTimer, flingTime=1f;
    private float velocityX;

    public ScrollWheel(Drawable wheelDrawable, Drawable wheelShading, Label label) {
        this.wheelDrawable = wheelDrawable;
        this.wheelShading = wheelShading;
        this.label = label;

        wheelWidth = (int)wheelDrawable.getMinWidth();
        separator = wheelWidth;

        setWidth(wheelDrawable.getMinWidth());
        setHeight(wheelDrawable.getMinHeight());

        // stops ScrollPane from overriding input events
        InputListener stopTouchDown = new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                event.stop();
                return false;
            }
        };
        addListener(stopTouchDown);

        ActorGestureListener flickScrollListener = new ActorGestureListener() {
            public void pan (InputEvent event, float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
                updateScroll(deltaX);
            }
            public void fling (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int button) {
                if (Math.abs(x) > 150) {
                    flingTimer = flingTime;
                    velocityX = x;
                }
            }
            public boolean handle (Event event) {
                if (super.handle(event)) {
                    if (((InputEvent)event).getType() == InputEvent.Type.touchDown) flingTimer = 0;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        addListener(flickScrollListener);
    }

    private void updateScroll(float delta){
        unscaledScrollValueX += (delta * direction);
        scrollValueX = (int)(unscaledScrollValueX / precision);

        isNotEdge = true;
        if (scrollValueX <= minValue){
            scrollValueX = minValue;
            unscaledScrollValueX = minValue * precision;
            isNotEdge = false;          
        }
        else if (scrollValueX >= maxValue){
            scrollValueX = maxValue;
            unscaledScrollValueX = maxValue * precision;
            isNotEdge = false;          
        }
        if (isNotEdge){         
            separator += delta;
            if (separator <= 0){
                separator = wheelWidth;
            }
            else if (separator >= wheelWidth) {
                separator = 0;
            }
        }

        updateLabel();      
    }
    private void updateLabel(){
        label.setText("" + scrollValueX);   
    }

    public void setMinValue(int minValue){ this.minValue = minValue; }
    public void setMinValueToNone(){ minValue=Integer.MIN_VALUE; }
    public void setMaxValue(int maxValue){ this.maxValue = maxValue; }
    public void setMaxValueToNone(){ minValue=Integer.MAX_VALUE; }
    public void setFlingTime(float flingTime){ this.flingTime = flingTime; }
    public void setPrecision(int precision){ this.precision = precision; }
    public void setRightPositiveDirection(boolean rightPositive){ direction = (rightPositive) ? 1 : -1; }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        super.act(delta);

        boolean animating = false;
        if (flingTimer > 0) {
            float alpha = flingTimer / flingTime;
            updateScroll(velocityX * alpha * delta);

            flingTimer -= delta;
            if (flingTimer <= 0) {
                velocityX = 0;
            }
            animating = true;
        }

        if (animating) {
            Stage stage = getStage();
            if (stage != null && stage.getActionsRequestRendering()){
                Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha){
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.flush();
        if (clipBegin(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight())){
            wheelDrawable.draw(batch, getX() + separator - wheelWidth, getY(), wheelDrawable.getMinWidth(), wheelDrawable.getMinHeight());      
            wheelDrawable.draw(batch, getX() + separator, getY(), wheelDrawable.getMinWidth(), wheelDrawable.getMinHeight());
            wheelShading.draw(batch, getX(), getY(), wheelShading.getMinWidth(), wheelShading.getMinHeight());
            batch.flush();
            clipEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great stuff! Didn't even know there was a ActorGestureListener but that's great and I should be able to fix my problem with dragging out actors from a scrollpane. Would love to see a video of it in action ;),

Comment: I guess I posted this to soon as there are still some bugs with the layout. I increased the size of the ScrollPane to allow the screen to scroll, but the scroll wheel didn't move with the ScrollPane. Also, apparently the table set was exactly the same size as the wheel actor which was cropping off the images that expanded outside of the wheel actor. Making the table wider exposed the extra images being drawn outside of the wheel. So now I'm trying to figure out how to crop the drawing to the stay within the actor (culling I'm assuming?)...will post an update when all of this is sorted.

Comment: Ok, I finally got the layout bugs fixed...as far as I know anyways. Hopefully I won't find anymore bugs. I will try to make a video of it tomorrow. I don't have the graphics done yet, so at the moment it's just a cheesy Paint doodle, but it's enough to see the mechanics in action.

Comment: I just added a video demoing the scroll wheel and made a few more updated to the code. At the moment I can't think of anything else to add to it, so I think it might be finished now. :)