# How to scroll vertical ScrollPane in horizontal ScrollPane properly? (LibGDX)

Tags: libgdx, scrollpane

I have made a horizontal pagedScrollPane according to tutorial [here](http://nexsoftware.net/wp/2013/05/09/libgdx-making-a-paged-level-selection-screen/). Every page consists of the table with normal vertical ScrollPane.

I need to scroll vertically if initial drag was vertical and scroll between pages if drag was horizontal. I realised that I had to do     `myScroll.setCancelTouchFocus(false);` with both scrollPanes to be able to activate the vertical scrollPane. Then I decided to setCancelTouchFocus to true if I want a scrollPane to disable.

```java
scrollVert.addListener(new DragListener() {

    @Override
    public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        if (!scrolling) {
            float dX = Math.abs(getDeltaX());
            float dY = Math.abs(getDeltaY());
            if (dX != 0 || dY != 0) {
                if (dX > dY) {
                    scrollPages.setCancelTouchFocus(true);
                } else {
                    scrollVert.setCancelTouchFocus(true);
                }
            scrolling = true;
            }
        }
        super.drag(event, x, y, pointer);
    }

    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {              
        scrolling = false;
        scrollPages.setCancelTouchFocus(false);
        scrollVert.setCancelTouchFocus(false);              
        super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I drag diagonally (or fast right and down) the scrollPane jumps a little bit sideways and only then decides where to scroll.

Comment: This is a hard one since either of the scroll able actors will take control of the dragging. There was a recent question about something similar, you might get going from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487020/how-to-scroll-a-scrollpane-in-code/35528949#comment58772721_35528949